# Button will not change to active when listbox is selected?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, listbox, tuples

I've made a function that creates a toplevel window with buttons and a listbox. I have an edit button to edit a selected item in said listbox, but I want this button disabled if nothing inside the listbox is selected.

```
def edit_page():
    window3 = Toplevel()
    frame3= Frame(window3)
    frame3.pack(side=TOP)
    color_list = Listbox(frame3)
    color_list.grid(row=1,column=0)

    edit_button = Button(frame3,text="Edit",command=fav_edit)
    edit_button.grid(row=4,column=4) 

    if len(color_list.curselection()) > 0  :
        edit_button.config(state=ACTIVE)
    else:
        edit_button.config(state=DISABLED)
```

The last thread was dead and it was filled with confusion, sorry.
It seems the if/else statement isn't working as intended. When I open this new window, the button is disabled, and when I click on the listbox, it stays disabled.
If I flip the ACTIVE and DISABLED states in the if/else, like:

```
    if len(color_list.curselection()) > 0  :
        edit_button.config(state=DISABLED)
    else:
        edit_button.config(state=ACTIVE)
```

The edit button is active, and will stay active even if the listbox is selected.
Is the window not updating? Do I need to try it another way? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: My listbox does include items/tuples inside of it even if it does not show it in this example of my project.

Comment: The if block will only be executed once just after the listbox and button are created.  You need to learn about event-driven programming which tkinter GUI is based on.

Answer (score 0):

Used a mouse event to call to a function to check the length of the tuple.

```
def edit_page():
    window3 = Toplevel()
    frame3= Frame(window3)
    frame3.pack(side=TOP)
    color_list = Listbox(frame3)
    color_list.grid(row=1,column=0)

    edit_button = Button(frame3,text="Edit",command=fav_edit)
    edit_button.grid(row=4,column=4) 

    color_list.bind("<Enter>",lambda *args: check_sel(edit_button,color_list.curselection()))

def check_sel(button,selection):
    if len(selection) > 0:
        button.config(state=ACTIVE)
    else:
        button.config(state=DISABLED)
```